# When function not supported in window function in pyspark?

Tags: pyspark, window, partition-by

I have a dataset of people in classes. Each person may be in multiple classes.

For each person in my dataset, I'm trying to determine whether or not an action took place in class after the date of their first test in that class. In other words, I am trying to partition by name and class before doing a calculation.

Here's what I have so far:

```
w2 = Window.partitionBy(["class", "name"]).orderBy(col("class"))
df_2 = df_1.withColumn("test_brightline",
              F.when((F.col("attendance_date") > F.col("first_test_date")), "after").otherwise("before").over(w2)).select("class","name","attendance_date", "test_brightline")
```

I get the following error:

```
AnalysisException: Expression 'CASE WHEN (attendance_date#125 > first_test_date#2549) THEN after ELSE before END' not supported within a window function.;
```

Is my coding wrong or does `Window` not accept the `when` function? If it's the latter, what can I use instead?

EDIT: as requested, adding sample input and expected output

Input:

| class | name | attendance_date | first_test_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Biology | Bob | 2-1-2020 | 12-1-2020 |
| Biology | Sam | 3-1-2020 | 4-1-2020 |
| English | Bob | 3-1-2020 | 3-5-2020 |
| English | Claire | 5-7-2020 | 6-12-2020 |

Output

| class | name | attendance_date | first_test_date | test_brightline |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Biology | Bob | 2-1-2020 | 12-1-2020 | before |
| Biology | Sam | 3-1-2020 | 4-1-2020 | before |
| English | Bob | 3-5-2020 | 3-1-2020 | after |
| English | Claire | 5-7-2020 | 6-12-2020 | before |

Thank you so much!

Comment: `when` is not a window function. Please add input and expected output to your question

Comment: @blackbishop good to know! just added input and expected output, thank you!

Comment: There is no need to use window. Simply remove the part `.over(w)` from what you already tried.

Comment: Wow I totally overthought this. Thank you!!